# Page is loading continuously when executing the selenium scripts, this is happening most of the time but some times able to proceed further

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Trying to execute the scripts am facing this page loading issue.

Included PageLoadStratergy.

```java
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", new String[] { "enable-automation" });
        options.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.EAGER);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Still facing the same.

Can anyone please help me to sort this out.